# How can I add my app as system app

Tags: java, android, system

Im developing an android keyboard.

I have to know how I can add my app as system app so,
my keyboard will be able to use everywhere in the phone like any keyboard.

As base im using this:[link](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app doesn't need to be a system app. System apps - are apps are apks bundled by manufacturer and resides in separate directory. 
You may check your AndroidManifest. Manifest must promote this app as IME.

Answer (score 0):

If you will add your apps in system apps section, you will create your own rom or rooted device. Maybe read [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1776095).